# Magento objects in *.phtml files

Tags: magento

1) What $this/$resource variables refer to in Magento .phtml files?

2) Where do I find the list of methods I can use with $this/$resource?

print_r displays huge objects which functionality is not very easy to understand.

Comment: you can use $this->getData();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't understand `$resource` that you are referencing with. But however `$this` stands for block that defines that template.

To make it more clear, suppose you have a layout code that seems like this

```
<some_handle>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="xxx/yyy" name="custom.block" as="custom.block" template="custom/template.phtml" />
    </reference>
</some_handle>
```

Now above in our demo layout, you can see a block is defined, which defines a template `template.phtml`. Now your template.phtml may look like this.

location : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/custom/template.phtml`

```
<div>
     <?php $value = $this->getSomeMethod(); ?>
</div>
```

Here `$this` stands for the block that holds this template. In this case, `$this` is an instance of `Namespace_Modulename_Block_Yyy` block. (assume `xxx` stand for `Namespace_Modulename` module.).

So the method `getSomeMethod()` is not defined in this class, it will definitely shows an error.

Hope that gives you an idea.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify. If $this refers to a block, then the block refers to app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/Block/yyy.php where getSomeMethod() is defined?

Answer (score 5):

The template files (`.phtml`) are included in the block methods so a proper html can be returned.  See the method `Mage_Core_Block_Template::fetchView`.
All of the block classes that have a template associated extend the `Mage_Core_Block_Template` class.

So `$this` is actually the current block class that is being used.
In theory one template can be used by multiple block classes. But this rarely happens.
If you don't know what `$this` is just add this in the template file:

```
echo get_class($this);
```

and you will get the class name.
If you want the available methods you can do this:

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r(get_class_methods($this));echo "</pre>";
```

But ...you will see that you are able to call some methods that don't really exist.
Because the class `Mage_Core_Block_Template` extends `Varien_Object` that implements the method [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) you will be able to call any method that starts with `get`, `set`, `uns`, `has` without getting an error even if the method does not exist.

I haven't seen a phtml with the variable `$resource` but you can treat that the same as `$this`.

Comment: +1 for your better theory class. My answer will provide an example, so that every one can easily understand :)

Comment: Nice explanation. Now I just need to know how to reliably determine to which .php file/class a <block> refers to? Also, can you recommend any documentation where methods as 'getLayout' or 'createBlock' are explained? Or should I look them up in the code.

Comment: This is all I have: http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2010/05/how-to-find-methods-in-magento.html. For the rest...Google is your friend.

Comment: Thanks Marius! It's a shame that I can't accept both answers as they are relevant and substitute each other.